# How to post the password using ajax and php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, post

I have a fixed username password and one variable text.

this is first method but **it's not safe**:

```
<form action="http://site.com/foo.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="user123" />
  <input type="hidden" name="password" value="pass123" />
<input type="text" name="text" />
<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

this is secound method Please complete this:

**index.html**

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**foo.php**

```
$username = "user123";
$password = "pass123";

$text = $_POST["text"];

$url  = "http://site.com/foo.php?text=".$text."&password=".$password."&username=".$username;
```

**HOW TO post *$url* safe? (without HTTPS)**

Comment: For one, it seems you are doing something fundamentally wrong if you need to pass a password around like that. Secondly, get HTTPS, the small cost is worth it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is that form meant to be filled up by a user?

Comment: You will probably want to `url_encode` the `$text` and `$username`. http://php.net/en/manual/function.url-encode.php

Comment: Oops - it's `urlencode`, not `url_encode`. http://php.net/en/manual/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **UPDATE:**
>
> You can't securely log in without HTTPS.
>   This is terribly insecure, and doesn't prevent people from logging in
>   if they intercept the hash.
>   Just use HTTPS.

---

Use the [MD5 function](http://php.net/en/manual/function.md5.php).

e.g.

```
$url = "http://example.com/foo.php?text=".$text."&password=".md5($password)."&username=".$username;
```

Then on the receiving site (`http://example.com/foo.php?...`), check the received password with a hash (MD5) of the actual password.

**Example:**

*sending file:*

```
$username = "user123";
$password = "pass123";

$text = $_POST["text"];

$url = "http://example.com/foo.php";
$data = "text=".$text."&password=".md5($password)."&username=".$username;

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
if($result) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Failed
}
```

*receiving file:*

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

// Insert code here to escape the username with mysqli_real_escape_string,
// then retrieve data from database with MySQLi.

if($password == md5($db_password)) {
    // Correct password
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect password.';
}
unset($username, $password, $db_password); // For security, remove variables from memory
```

Comment: I not receiving data, a server receive data.

Comment: @Sinac - Why do you say that? `curl` can send data, as it is in my answer.

Comment: get error in line 8 (md5) : syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE  ,  I test in localhost easyphp

Comment: @Sinac - Sorry, I forgot a semicolon. The previous line should read `$url = "http://site.com/foo.php";`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: What if a man in the middle monitored the line to the server that hashes the password, wouldn't he still get the clear-text password? Also, if he monitored the line to the other server, he'd get the hash too, so wouldn't he be able to use it to log in?

Comment: @Kebman Wow, this answer is old...
Yeah, that's true. None of this is safe, HTTPS is required for actual security.

Comment: I gather people still glean wisdom also from old information, so if nobody tells anyone that something is unsafe, chances are the methods will be used uncritically.

Answer (score 2):

There is no safe without HTTPS.

Because when you send the password even if you encrypt it, the network relay nodes will get access to it and they can use it that way.

You can only MD5 to prevent password observing, but it's yet accessible.

But in HTTPS which is an encryption by itself, the password can't be broken because there is a public and private key which is known only to client and server.

Maybe you can do the login through HTTPS. There is no need to buy a certificate. you can easily issue one yourself and setup it on your host.

Use HTTPS for important business.

Comment: HOW TO post $url ? I want post aging $url.

Comment: I don't get you. What do you mean by posting $url?

Comment: (persian?) in foo.php we get some information like text from index.php and add username and password , now we have a $url that content user+pass+text. now we want send it to server.

Comment: yes, I'm. Why do you want to send the data again to another file. Just do the login on the first file and if it is successful redirect the user afterwards.